# Extract first word from string in Python

Tags: python

I have Python strings that follow one of two formats:

```
"@gianvitorossi/ FALL 2012 #highheels ..."
```

OR:

```
"@gianvitorossi FALL 2012 #highheels ..."
```

I want to extract just the `@gianvitorossi` portion.

I'm trying the following:

```
    ...
    company = p['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text'] 
    company = company.replace('/','')
    company = company.replace('\t','')
    company = company.replace('\n','')
    c = company.split(' ')
    company = c[0]
```

This works in some of the names. However, in the example below:
[image]

My code is returning `@gianvitorossi FALL` rather than just `@gianvitorossi` as expected.

Comment: is it possible that it's not space, but e.g. tab `\t`? can you provide some examples, incl. the output when you print their representation. If it was space, split at space and then just removing trailing slash using `rstrip()` should work. `your_text.split(' ')[0].rstrip('/')`

Comment: I've added a screenshot above and have removed slashes, tabs, and newlines. Are there any other characters that would render as a space in the .json file (when opened in Notepad) but would be interpreted as something else by Python?

Comment: show the output when `print(repr(p['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text']))` for the case when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should split with the '/' character

```
    company = "mystring"
    c = company.split('/')
    company = c[0]
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. The OP seems to getting an additional string even when splitting at a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

well it worked on my machine. for ending characters such as slash, you can use rstrip(your_symbols).

Comment: I added some edits above, any thoughts on other characters that might appear to be a space but wouldn't be interpreted as one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could do that using regular expression, here what you could do

```
import re 
text1 = "@gianvitorossi/ FALL 2012 #highheels ..."
text2 = "@gianvitorossi FALL 2012 #highheels ..."
patt = "@[A-Za-z]+"
print(re.findall(patt, text1))
```

if your text might include numbers you could modify the code to be as follows

```
import re 
text1 = "@gianvitorossi/ FALL 2012 #highheels ..."
text2 = "@gianvitorossi FALL 2012 #highheels ..."
patt = "@[A-Za-z0-9]+"
print(re.findall(patt, text1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using `split` and `replace`, which if your requirements above are exhaustive, should be enough:

```
s.split(' ')[0].replace('/','')
```

An example:

```
s = ["@gianvitorossi/ FALL 2012 #highheels ...","@gianvitorossi FALL 2012 #highheels ..."]
for i in s:
    print(i.split(' ')[0].replace('/',''))

@gianvitorossi
@gianvitorossi
```

Comment: I added some edits above, any thoughts on other characters that might appear to be a space but wouldn't be interpreted as one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don‘t want to use regular expressions, you could use this:

```
original = "@gianvitorossi/ FALL 2012 #highheels ..."
extract = original.split(' ')[0]

if extract[-1] == "/":
  extract = extract[:-1]
```